# How to switch standby to master on postgresql 13?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-replication, postgresql-cluster

For High Availability on DB was build Active-Standby(replica) cluster on Postgresql-13. Inserting data correctly transfer to 'replica' server, it is ok.
Now, I want check case, how i can make change roles on two servers.
for this I the /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/standby.signal was delete, also for apply changes restarted postgrsql.service
Something tells me what I'm doing wrong.
So,

1. how to make a master out of a replica,
2. how then from the old master (which was temporarily not available) to make the master back, without losing data?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: In a HA, you should be able to turn off a switch port on the primary, initiate your failover process, and do the reverse to fail back. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrewind.html "A typical scenario is to bring an old primary server back online after failover as a standby that follows the new primary."

Comment: thx sir, data was success transfer to old-master, but i have one issue, how now to make a replica-srv a replica? (I made changes on the master, but this data did not go to the replica)

Comment: now I created a slot on the master, and again reconnected the replica, and it works. I don’t know if I’m configure true(according to the documentation), but now the changes in the master appear in the replica